# WPF ICommand.Execute on UI, XP

Tags: c#, wpf, icommand

I have a `UserControl` within a `Window` on my WPF application.

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
        <Button Command="{Binding AddFileCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

In the model I have declared and initialized an `AddFileCommand` variable:

```
public ICommand AddFileCommand { get; set; }

public XXXModel()
{
    AddFileCommand = new DelegateCommand(o => true, AddFile);
}
```

The best solution would be appreciated using `ICommand`s instead of `Click` events.

Under Windows XP, clicking on this button doesn't fire the AddFile(object parameter) function. On Windows Vista/Windows 7, it works like a charm. Calling `ICommand.Execute()` directly from code works under XP as well.

I tried updating the .NET framework (the project uses .NET 4.0), but still there is a lack in the code.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Which DelegateCommand? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654427.aspx?

Comment: Yes, that one I'm using.

Comment: Well that constructor takes an `Action` to execute as the first parameter, not the second.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned by @ta.speot.is, the [**DelegateCommand**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654427.aspx) constructor takes first argument as **Action<T>** to be called, and the second is the **Func<T, bool>** referred to CanExecute().

Your `Execute` method will execute **Func<T, bool>**, rather than **Action<T>**. It could not work on one OSs, and not working on another.